# Sh script to attach to existing screen and use command

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I have a process running in a screen. I attach it via:

```
screen -x root/sc_name
```

And I need to stop this process from this screen using `stop` command. You don't execute command on Linux terminal, it has own terminal like `mysql>`.

I want to stop it because I will take a backup. While it's not stopped, back up process can be bugged (the process is a Minecraft server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider [setting up Minecraft server as Systemd service](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Server_startup_script#Systemd_Script), so you can easily stop the process, create your backup and get it running again after that process finishes.

Comment: Hm, I will review this full systemd config and apply on my server but that was what I need in that tutorial, thanks so much: `usr/bin/screen -p 0 -S mc-%i -X eval 'stuff "stop"\\015'`